# Создать portable версию из MEVN приложения

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongodb, powershell, hosting

Есть full-stack application, где :

```
front-end: Vue.js 2
back-end: Node.js + Express
database: MongoDB + mongoose
```

требуется сделать portable-версию этого под windows

Чтобы тот, кому я сбросил это, мог поднять локально без всяких танцев с бубнами и в один клик

Есть ли готовые tools для этого? Или есть хостинги под такой app на бесплатной основе?

Или придётся использовать docker/powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron.js (как обёртка над MEVN) + PowerShell .NET для создания Executable application оказалось лучшим решением